# What types of jobs did upper class Romans do?

Tags: ancient-history, roman-empire, 1st-century

I am working on a book based on the first century, I need to know the types of jobs you'd need to be in the upper class, as well as the poor.

Comment: Being upper class meant that you didn't have a 'job', pretty much by definition, other than being in the Senate or elected/appointed to some upper-level government position.

Comment: Prior to the Industrial Revolution, "upper class" was almost synonymous with "landowner". "Job" was a lower class activity.   I recommend that you look into latifundia, which will help you to understand the economy.  You'll also want to understand client/patron relationships, the bread dole, and Roman gangs.

Comment: And of course, there is the "[cursus honorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursus_honorum)" but they were public offices and not "jobs" (and in fact, IIRC, many of them were not only not paid at all(except with bribes and other corrupt practices) but involved paying for the expenses of the position).

Comment: Thank you for this information,  I also would like to know how one could lose their stature? In my book, the character,  starts off in a upper class family but something happened so which makes her and her family divided, and throw  into prison to await their trial for something,  like there religious beliefs. (I am still working out the story line) don't want to give to much away because I plan to publish my work once I'm done.

Comment: Being implicated in a political conspiracy of some kind was a bad career move

Comment: Ne Mo - Being implicated in an unsuccessful political conspiracy was a bad career move, but not a successful one.  "treason doth never prosper what's the reason.  If it prosper none dare call it treason."

Comment: user24015 - being on the losing side in some political/military etc. conflict could always be bad for one's status & health.  If someone was a non Roman aristocrat they would be more likely to get in trouble than a Roman aristocrat.  A merchant or landowner could lose his wealth due to business problems, disasters, extravagance, etc. A number of different family members can die, be killed in battle, be arrested, lose expensive elections, face bankruptcy, go senile, be crippled, anger the Emperor, etc. etc. etc. at the same time, drastically lowering the wealth and status of the survivors.l

Answer (score 18):

There is an ample evidence (from authors like Plutarch, Cicero etc.) that the only
occupations which were considered appropriate for the Romans from good families
were military, politics, administration, law and literature. (To be sure many of them were involved in business but they did not like to advertise this).  Doctors, engineers, artists (including painters, sculptors etc.) and architects were definitely out of the list of desirable professions for a noble.
Let me illustrate this by a cite from Plutarch:

> In other cases, admiration of the deed is not immediately accompanied by
> an impulse to do it. Nay, many times, on the contrary, while we delight in
> the work, we despise the workman, as, for instance, in the case of perfumes
> and dyes; we take a delight in them, but dyers and perfumers we regard as
> illiberal and vulgar folk. Therefore it was a fine saying of Antisthenes,
> when he heard that Ismenias was an excellent piper: "But he's a worthless man,"
> said he, "otherwise he wouldn't be so good a piper." And so Philip once said
> to his son, who, as the wine went round, plucked the strings charmingly and
> skilfully, "Art thou not ashamed to pluck the strings so well?" It is enough, surely,
> if a king have leisure to hear others pluck the strings, and he pays great
> deference to the Muses if he be but a spectator of such contests.

> Labour with one's own hands on lowly tasks gives witness, in the toil thus
> expended on useless things, to one's own indifference to higher things.
> No generous youth, from seeing the Zeus at Pisa, or the Hera at Argos,
> longs to be Pheidias or Polycleitus; nor to be Anacreon or Philetas or
> Archilochus out of pleasure in their poems. For it does not of necessity follow
> that, if the work delights you with its grace, the one who wrought it is worthy of your esteem.

(Plutarch, Pericles I-II).

Remark. To be in upper class in Ancient Rome was not the same as to be rich. We know that some freedmen (former slaves) were richer than some senators. But the most prestigious jobs were closed to them. The crucial thing was your family, ancestors. However this gradually changed with time.

Especially despicable were all kinds of jobs related to public performances. It seems that the emperors like Nero, Commodus and Elagabal were hated first of all for their public performances, rather then for being murderers. They are unanimously rated worst emperors, though some others killed more people and performed worse.

Comment: IIRC, members of the Senate were formally barred from being directly involved in 'trade' - although I suspect this was more honoured in the breach! ;-)

Comment: @TheHonRose: yes, this is correct. Tacitus even mentions one person who resigned from senatorial class to be able to do business. On the other hand, to qualify for senate a person had to have very substantial total worth. These rules seem contradictive to each other.

Comment: I seem to remember that senators **did** engage in business, but at one remove, as it were, through "straw men" - freedmen, clients etc - but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Alex, a major source of wealth at the time was landholdings.

Comment: @Mark: Correct. But landholding is not a profession and (usually) not a job. Though you are right in that agriculture was a kind of respectable occupation. For example, nobody blamed Diocletian when he retired from his emperor job and started to grow cabbage.